# how to Write rewrite rules for full URLs in web.config in a DNN website?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, multiple-domains

I am working with DNN website, which works with different domains, i mean to say one website is working with multiple domains, layout and pages all categorizes with Different portals. every Portal has its own pages and content. Now i have to write some rewrite rules for the different portal. for main portal i have used the following concept to write the rule :

```
<rule name="r7" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^vows/tabid/(.*)id/([0-9]+)/Default.aspx" ignoreCase="true"/>
                <action type="Redirect" url="/plan/brochure.aspx"/>
            </rule>
```

Now for another domain(portal) example www.abc.uk.co. how can i write rules for this portal. if i write the URL in rule it does not work for me. and if i write in the above format then it cause to redirect for first domain also.

Please help me how can i achieve my goal. any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: may be this like will help you. https://openurlrewriter.codeplex.com/discussions/453392

Answer (score 1):

here is the code worked for me:

```
<rule name="Uk1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^man/mostpopulararticles/brides.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?abc.co.uk$" />            
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/man.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

Thanks All

Answer (score 1):

you can use Url Rewriting feature of dotnetnuke you can get detail on this link

**http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/page/url-rewriting**

you have write rule in below path

Config\SiteUrls.config

```
 <RewriterRule>
            <LookFor>.*testwebserice.asmx(.*)</LookFor>
            <SendTo>/DesktopModules/Projectname/Web service/testwebserice.asmx$1</SendTo>
        </RewriterRule>
```